# How to detect a current browser tab is changes to another tab or the browser window is minimized

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I need to detect my current browser tab is changed to another tab or the window is minimized.
Simply the operation is to show desktop notification like gmail so that when only i changed the tab or minimized the window the notification of new mail and chat comes. I need to check it through javascript.Is there any method to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript

Comment: You can take a look at this question for the focus

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active/1760268#1760268