# How to check if an application is minimized in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, minimize

I have an application that plays audio. I need to add an event that checks if the application is minimized and stop the audio if it is so. All of the responses I found were given for Cordova, where the following Eventlistener works just fine:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onMinimizedApplication());
```

My question is: Is there a way to determine whether an application is minimized at the moment ?

Comment: In what and where are you trying to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: @JonB, I am asking about an application, not a browser.

Comment: If the application supports javascript then it should soon support Visibility API as in the answer of the duplicate answer. Otherwise specify the javascript engine in your application.