# Minimize Browser Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read [How to detect browser minimize and maximize state in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript) post, but it is getting the state of a browser. But is there any event that triggers when a browser is minimize and maximize like `resize()` or something ?

I think there is other-way-around like to check `document.hidden` state periodically using `setInterval()` but this is not I want. I want clean and clear way that run on all new browsers.

Comment: The top answer in the question you linked mentions the `visibilitychange` event.